# Scriptural source for Ganesha's vahana 'Dinka'

Tags: ganesha, name, reference-request, vahana

Before today, I only knew two names for Ganesha's vahana:

- 'Mooshika'
- '[Krouncha](https://www.indianetzone.com/64/legend_lord_ganesha_krauncha.htm)'

But then I learned of another name for that mouse, Dinka. Searching google for `dinka ganesha` offers 7 lakh + results, so it's clearly a thing known by many people.

[Here is one blog](http://ashokkoul.blogspot.com/2021/11/vahana.html) using the name:

> In Hindu iconography, positive aspects of the vehicle are often emblematic of the deity that it carries. [...] **Dinka the mouse**, vehicle of Ganesha, represents speed and sharpness.

**What is the scriptural basis for the name 'Dinka' to refer to the mouse Ganesha rides?** If it's of a non-scriptural basis, what region or tradition does it arise from?